# How to remove double qoutes when reading csv from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv and trying to have it as a list of list.

```
operational_band,alternative_band
V490,null
V550,null
V620,null
V670,null
V708,V710
N740,null
N753,N760
N778,N780
N865,N860
```

I am reading the file as:

```
df = pd.read_csv("op_bands.csv")
op_list = df.values.tolist()
print(op_list)
```

I get op_list as:

```
[['V620', ' "null"'], 
 ['V670', ' "null"'], 
 ['V708', ' "V710"'], 
 ['N740', ' "null"'], 
 ['N753', ' "N760" '], 
 ['N778', ' "N780"'], 
 ['N865', ' "N860"']]
```

1. My 1st and 2nd entry were ignored, why? And how to fix that?
2. The 2nd entries from each list have double quotes and space e.g. `' "N860"'`. How to ignore these quotes and extra space/s?
3. My CSV format is right, isn't it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output.

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: All the rows without quotes: `[['V490', nan],
 ['V550', nan],
 ['V620', nan],
 ['V670', nan],
 ['V708', 'V710'],
 ['N740', nan],
 ['N753', 'N760'],
 ['N778', 'N780'],
 ['N865', 'N860']]`.

Answer (score 2):

When I tried to replicate this, by copy-pasting what you wrote into a csv file, I did not have the same problem.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dummy.csv')
op_list = df.values.tolist()
print(op_list)
    
>>>[['V490', nan], ['V550', nan], ['V620', nan], ['V670', nan], ['V708', 'V710'], ['N740', nan], ['N753', 'N760'], ['N778', 'N780'], ['N865', 'N860']]
```

Looks like an encoding error. Are you sure your input was encoded with utf-8? Here are python's standard encodings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
You can these encodings like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dummy.csv', encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 1):

When I copy pasted your data I didn't have your problem. This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', keep_default_na=False)
lsls = df.values.tolist()
```

use `keep_default_na=False` to correctly cast 'null' to string and not to `nan`.
Try upgrading to last version of Pandas.